# Can't click while moving

Tags: technical-issues, terraria, mouse

I started a new game on Terraria on a new computer. The game isn't responding to my mouse clicks when my character is moving, though. My character has to come to a complete stop before the game handles any of my left mouse clicks.

What might be causing this behavior? How can I fix it?

Comment: How is your internet connection? What is your computers specs? Does it persist when you use another mouse?

Comment: I'm playing single player, so I don't think my Internet connection matters. I've tried two mice, both of which work as expected outside of Terraria but have the same problems in the game.

Comment: what about your computer specs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/1xd0g6/cant_move_mouse_while_walking/) is a reddit post about the same issue and how to fix it:

> I've had a small issue with Terraria for a long time now: while I have the a or d key held down (to move), I sometimes can't move my mouse cursor. I'm on a laptop, and I have a feeling that may be linked to it. There is a way to temporarily fix it by opening and closing my inventory, but it feels clumsy. Does anybody else have this problem? Any advice?
>
> EDIT: This issue has been resolved; you go into 'Mouse' and look around a bit until you find 'PalmCheck', and disable it.

You can also try the smart cursor settings.

From the main menu go to:

*Settings > General > Smart Cursor Mode*

Try toggling that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while playing Minecraft on my laptop on Windows 8.1 and using the built-in mouse buttons (not an external mouse).  Trying to left-click (to mine or attack) while pressing the WASD keys to move around didn't work; it did work when standing still.

Here's the solution on Windows 8.1 laptops:

- Open the Charms bar (move the mouse to the lower-right corner of the screen and then up), and select Settings
- At the bottom of the Charms bar, click "Change PC Settings".
- Open "PC and Devices."
- Open "Mouse and Touchpad".
- Under "Touchpad", set the dropdown to "No delay (always on)".

The culprit here is that Windows is trying to prevent the other problem that can happen when you're typing on the keyboard, and your hands graze the laptop's touchpad, causing an inadvertent click, which can result in the active window losing focus in the middle of your typing.

While you're playing a game like Minecraft or Terraria, though, you *want* to be able to hit letter keys and click mouse buttons at the same time!

Comment: +1. I think your solution may be more dependent on which brand of trackpad you're using than which operating system you have. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In **Windows 10**, the proper setting is:

Settings > Devices > Touchpad (left nav) > Touchpad Sensitivity (dropdown) > Most Sensitive

Note: Despite the misleading name of this Windows setting ("Sensitivity"), it does indeed control Windows' behavior of *disabling* the trackpad left mouse button for a short time after a keyboard key is pressed!

Comment: -1: As the other answers indicated, the problem was that I had a setting turned on that disabled the trackpad when I was typing, not that the trackpad wasn't sensitive enough.

Comment: @Kevin: Despite the misleading name of this Windows setting ("Sensitivity"), it does indeed control Windows' behavior of *disabling* the trackpad left mouse button for a short time after a keyboard key is pressed. If you have a copy of Windows 10 handy, I'd encourage you to give it a try and test the accuracy of this answer for yourself!

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that. I apologize for the downvote. If you edit your answer, I'll remove it.